# Disable Libraries window popup when explorer restarted

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I have written an application that changes some of the registry settings and then restarts explorer to save them. Everytime explorer is restarted an annoying "Libraries" popup comes up.

I want to disable it somehow though C# code, (probably by tweaking some other registry keys). However, I do NOT want to disable libraries feature, just a popup that comes up when explorer is restarted.

All articles on the web show how to disable libraries completely.

Comment: Please don't add things like " C# .NET Windows 7" to your titles. That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: What in the world are you doing that requires directly changing registry settings and forcing explorer to restart? At the very least that would lead to a bad user experience. Honestly what you trying to do sounds suspicious. [What is the end goal you're trying to achieve here](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? There might be a better way.

Comment: I need to do it. It is a special app that is meant to change desktop background, get system settings, disable icons, auto-hide task bar etc. It is used in one of the computer stores to display computer sale sticker directly on the screen.

Comment: @user979632: You're not exempt from proper programming techniques just because your application is special. You're basically asking for a kiosk mode of some sort, which is something that's been done many times now. There's lots of questions on Stack Overflow about it already.

Comment: something like that. My app has an ability to change background when user clicks a button (different background colours are used to represent sales and specials). Everything works perfectly, just that annoying libraries popup that comes up every time explorer is restarted. It is not a show stopper, but it is very annoying as you have to close it everytime you update screen state.

Comment: it is not my app that needs to occupy the whole screen. App runs only on demand. My application changes desktop background. So maybe, it is not realy a kiosk mode as such

Comment: @user979632: That shouldn't require an Explorer.exe restart. The Windows OS exposes a public API for changing the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: I still want to show windows, just no icons, no task bar, no widgets. It all works fine.

Comment: Hiding icons and auto-hiding taskbar requires explorer restart to permanetly save settings for the next restart.

Comment: Trust me I tried lots of code to do it and in the end restarting explorer makes sure everything is saved and next time windows is restarted changes persist. Anyway, my question is HOW TO DISABLE LIBRARIES POPUP

Comment: There is a group policy to hide icons, and you can use SHAppBarMessage to turn on autohide, no explorer restart necessary.

Comment: On my box, restarting Explorer does not cause a "libraries popup".  What does this popup look like?

Comment: One of those: http://www.google.com.au/imgres?q=libraries+windows+7+popup&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&rls=com.microsoft:en-au:IE-SearchBox&biw=1401&bih=724&tbm=isch&tbnid=qolM_1y7sY4KQM:&imgrefurl=http://www.productkeyfind.com/blog/Libraries-Windows-7-Ultimate-Product-Boast-Adapt/&docid=PbG4wANf_Cd7CM&itg=1&w=560&h=432&ei=H9aLTtaqFOKImQX2wfSPBA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=578&page=4&tbnh=145&tbnw=188&start=52&ndsp=17&ved=1t:429,r:11,s:52&tx=117&ty=59

Comment: SHAppBarMessage didnt seem to work properly and setings did not persist after restart. I tried 3 different code snippets on 4 machines. It hides it, but then it is very buggy. Same for hiding icons. I dont want to use some group policies. CAN you just answer my question on how to change registry to hide libraries popup

Comment: I thought your settings change was intended to be temporary (only when your program is running). Explorer saves its settings when you log off, which naturally doesn't happen if you outright kill it. Also, Explorer does not normally show the Libraries window when it restarts, so there is something peculiar about your situation. You need to share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When restarting explorer I just had to add some randow parameter as it seems to default to Libraries window. so calling "explorer.exe xxx" would cause explorer to ignore default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this to happen is that the Libraries window was open the last time Explorer was shut down naturally, i.e., the last time the user logged off.  If you close the window and log off, then log in again, your software will probably work correctly.

Caveat: killing and restarting the explorer process is inherently risky.  Resolving this particular issue does not mean that other similar issues won't show up in future.